# ASP.NET Ajax and "could not load type"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET web page with an Ajax file upload control.  When I try to run my page, I'm told "Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler' from assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit'."

Here's my control:

```
<ajaxtoolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Here's the relevant stuff in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
            type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
            AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Here's my error message:

[image: error message]

I'm running this app on Win Server 2k3 and IIS 6 and ASP.NET 4.  It appears that my toolkit is the correct version.

I feel like it's probably a simple mistake, but I can't seem to find it.  Let me know if more info is helpful.  Thanks!

Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. Do a search for deleting ASP temporary files. If that does not solved it, sometimes a reinstall of Ajax using package manager sometimes resolved it.

Comment: "Common problem" makes me feel better.  I've just cleaned out temp files with no success.  I'll see if I can reinstall Ajax next.

Comment: Also try to clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Copy the AjaxControlToolkit.dll into the /bin folder of the web site application

Comment: Okay, reinstalled Ajax tools with NuGet, cleaned and rebuilt project, and made sure that the DLL was in my bin folder.  Still in the same place.

Comment: I removed the HTTP handler that [http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) and now the page loads.  So, I'm going to go ahead and see what happens if I write code for this control.

Comment: Okay, long story as short as possible: Re-installing the Ajax tools via NuGet was the secret fix.  I added the httpHandler back and I just had a successful upload.  Awesome.  Thanks a ton!  Have an awesome day!

Comment: Glad it is all sorted out.  When I forget again, at least I know it's documented somewhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

Even I had this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ztJI.jpg)

Well, I solved by removing AjaxFileUploadHandler fro Web.Config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <!--add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/-->
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <!--add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/-->
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This solved my error above.